# How to rotate markers in qwt

Tags: qt, qwt

I want to rotate my marker in my plot but i cant. Here is my code to adding images to plot:

```
    QPixmap pixmap("myImage");

    QwtSymbol *symbol = new QwtSymbol;
    symbol->setPixmap(pixmap);

    marker = new QwtPlotMarker;
    marker->setSymbol( symbol);
    marker->attach(this);
```

I tried to rotate with QTransform but i couldnt achive. Is there any trick to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this method to solve this problem.

```
QPixmap pixmap("myPic");
QMatrix rm;
rm.rotate(angle);
pixmap = pixmap.transformed(rm);

QwtPlotMarker *marker = new QwtPlotMarker;
marker->setSymbol( symbol);
marker->attach(myPlot);
```